# Spring Cloud Stream multiple destination bindings

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

As described in the documentation of Spring Cloud https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/multi/multi__configuration_options.html, it is possible to bind a channel to multiple destinations.

However, it is not described how messages from each channel will be processed. Is this processed in parallel, round-robin, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `round-robin` doesn't even apply to to your question, since load balancing implies multiple consumers to a single destination. You are simply asking about binding multiple destination to a channel which is nothing more than a bridge between external destination and internal destination.

Now if you have multiple listeners on the *internal destination* (such as channel), then `round-robin` applies as a default load balancing policy, but by that time it's already pushed down the stack to [spring-integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) framework which handles it. So you can read more on different load balancing policy if that is what you were asking about.

That said, you're also looking at the rather old documentation. We are at [3.0.0.RELEASE](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) now and promoting a different programming model which is much simpler. You can read our [release announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/25/announcing-the-release-of-spring-cloud-stream-horsham-3-0-0-release) which contains links to 4 different posts (in Quick highlights section) providing more details.